# Infinite sum of squared difference of Bessel functions separated by 4 indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I am trying to complete a proof which demands showing the equality

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( J_{n-1}(x) - J_{n+3}(x) \right)^2 = 1, \qquad \forall \, x\geq0$$

where $J_n$ are the [Bessel functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1).

I've computed the sum numerically up to a few finite $n_{\max}$ and it seems as though the sum is indeed converging to 1 for all values of $x$ within the range [0,100]. Please see the attached plot. If anyone has a way of proving this equality I'd be very interested in learning your approach!

---

[image: Infinite Bessel Function Sum - Numerical Convergence]

---

**Solutions**

[image: Solution: Part 1]

---

[image: Solution: Part 2]

Comment: Expand the square, then use the relations $10.23.3$ and $10.23.4$ [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23) as well as $J_{-1}=-J_1$

Comment: Thank you @Sal! For anyone interested in the explicit derivation steps I've attached images of the solution to the post.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: What is the source of the screenshots?

Comment: They're taken from a LaTex note I've written for a separate project.